# Order students' total scores from highest to lowest

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to arrange students' total scores from highest to lowest on a table

This is what I have so far...

Model:

```
 public function getTotalMarksForStudnets($subject_id,$student_id,$table,$totField){
    $this->db->select_max($totField);
    $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);  
    $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);
    $this->db->order_by("$totField", "DESC"); 
    $q = $this->db->get($table);
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        return  $q->row()->$totField;
    }else{
        return '0'; 
    }
  }
```

The view:

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;">
        <?php 
          $totalMarks = $this->student_model->getTotalMarksForStudnets($tmrow['subject_id'],$stdName['pstudent_id'],$table,$totField);
         $gtotal =  $gtotal + $totalMarks;
         if($totalMarks!=0){
          $totSubjects =  $totSubjects + 1;
         }
        echo $totalMarks;
        ?></td>
```

Comment: `students` ->means multiple student? then no need to pass student id an remove student id query from function as well. after that grab all data and apply a loop to show all data. since you have `DESC` in query so nothing to do extra at query level

Comment: I can't figure out with which part of the problem you're struggling. You seem to have everything you need.